# How do marine mammals stay hydrated?

Tags: metabolism, mammals, marine-biology, hydration

This is a question that has always bothered me. A quick internet search yields "metabolic processes" as the reason for how marine mammals obtain water, but what are those processes and why don't land mammals have them? In other words, **what are the specific differences between marine and non-marine mammals in how they stay hydrated?**

Comment: @Charles correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't marine biology (and the word *marine*) referring directly to the ocean and therefore salt water?

Comment: Upon searching google, there are dozens of results that directly answer this. For example, [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-can-sea-mammals-drink/). However, it seems that you're asking two separate questions in your post, those being: 1) "How do marine mammals stay hydrated?" and, 2) "Why don't land mammals have those [metabolic processes] too?". I would suggest focusing on just one.

Comment: "For most whales and dolphins, however, we simply do not know how they get their water, because it is difficult to observe these animals." That is a troubling line :( The article seemed to conclude that some marine mammals have more efficient kidneys?

Comment: *"... **marine mammals that feed on fish consume food with a salt content similar to that of their own blood, thereby avoiding the problem entirely**. Indeed, a study of California sea lions showed that, on a diet of fish, **these animals can live without drinking fresh water at all**. Some species of seals and sea lions apparently do drink seawater at least occasionally, as do common dolphins and sea otters, but **the practice is very rare in some other species**."*